# Discord.py Cogs Error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './cogs'

Tags: python, macos, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot with cogs and when i run the code i get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './cogs'
```

the code is:

```
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

the cogs folder is in the same directory as the Main.py
I am running MacOS and i cant use an absolute path as I'm going to be uploading this to heroku. Thanks in advance, if you need any more information dont hesitate to comment!

Comment: Does `os.listdir(".")` display the contents of the directory you think it should?

Comment: Adding onto @PatrickHaugh's comment - if you don't get the path working, you can simply put all of your other cogs into the same folder as `main.py` and you'll be able to run them with just the filename

Comment: thank you! so much!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is almost certainly that the current working directory is not the one above the cogs directory. The following is the code I use to load all the cogs for my bot:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import realpath, split, join, splitext
for item in listdir(join(split(realpath(__file__))[0], "cogs")):
    client.load_extension("cogs." + splitext(item)[0])
```